# Save html as pdf in node-webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, wkhtmltopdf, node-webkit

I'm working on a node-webkit desktop app for windows and I'm trying to find the best way to allow the user to save an html table view as a pdf from the application. The application has to run out of the box, so I can't ask the user to install any third party programs to get functionality working. I found a couple of solutions using wkhtmltopdf and phantomjs, but am unable to figure out a way to integrate them into the project so they run out of the box(if that is even possible). I got the node module pdfkit working within the project, but that doesn't convert html.

So my question is is there any solutions I could integrate with node-webkit that would allow me to save html as pdf out of the box?

Comment: did you look at http://www.html2pdf.it/

Comment: Why don't you just include wkhtmltopdf or phantomjs and the dependencies with your project? They don't need to be necessarily installed in a specific location. They can be in same directory as your application.

Comment: do you have any advice in how to do this? I'm relatively new to using node-webkit so adding dependencies is not something im familiar with.

Comment: I think you should copy the chrome pdf plugin to nw (its the file called libpdf.so (linux) and pdf.dll or some (windows) that file makes available see pdf like html pages but im not sure if its also used to make the html2pdf chrome printer